Looking for the title of a short story (?)
It involves a woman on a farm after world war two.
She has two farmhands, one a former Nazi, the other a former allied soldier.
Also there's the proverbial macguffin, providing the "science" of the story.
The macguffin was hidden on the farm by either the woman or one of the men, I'm not sure but one of the men might be killed at the end of the story.
Since part of the intrigue was that both men could stay on her farm, as long as they tolerated each other.
I think the macguffin had something to do with time, as far as I remember it was small enough to be hidden in a haystack.
(Seriously a macguffin with tentacles, tell me about that one. And is a macguffin with tentacles, technically, still a macguffin?)
Obviously the macguffin was a piece of machinery, small enough to be hand-held.
And yes, most certainly advanced tech.
It's a very simple story really, 3 main characters, and rather pastoral.
Not much happens, I think the story revolved around keeping the macguffin safe. Other than the obvious dynamics between the two men
Actually, to be totally honest (you people are gonna hate me), but the story might not be done be a genre writer.
As I've always read more "high" literature than genre (perhaps a literature writer infusing some SF ?), I
came late to genre fiction.
The story has a pastoral sense, think Clifford d. Simak (still my favorite sf writer), but with a  more "literate" sense (?).
Most likely it would have been from a short story collection of one particular writer, rather than from an anthology.
Also, I apologize, I'm not quite sure it was a short story.
But I figured the particulars, though sparse, were quite telling and memorable (i.e. WW2)
Most likely a golden age writer, during that time I wasn't reading a lot of contemporary SF.
I hope someone can help me out, this particular itch has been irritating me for a couple of years now.

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. When did you read this? Was it part of an anthology of short stories, or from a magazine or newspaper? If you remember any extra details, please [edit] them in

And do you remember anything about the maguffin? Was it advanced technology? Magic artifact? Evidence of Atlantis?

Tell us about the MacGuffin. Was it animal, vegetable, or mineral? Was it bigger than a breadbox? Was it spherical or cubical? Did it levitate? Did it glow in the dark? Did it have tentacles?

What happens in the story?

"Obviously" the MacGuffin was a piece of machinery, small enough to be held in the hand. Not obvious or even hinted at in your original post. What else are you holding back that might help to narrow down the search space? Doyou recall what part of the world the farm was in? Europe, South America, Africa, Kansas? About how long ago did you read it?

I don't understand the reference to tentacles. Did the object hidden in the haystack have tentacles?
